# Convert string to array in without using Split function

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Is there any way to convert a string (`"abcdef"`) to an array of string containing its character (`["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`) without using the `String.Split` function?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So you want an array of `string`, one `char` each:

```
string s = "abcdef";
string[] a = s.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

This works because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. So `Select(c => c.ToString())` projects each `char` in the `string` to a `string` representing that `char` and `ToArray` enumerates the projection and converts the result to an array of `string`.

If you're using an older version of C#:

```
string s = "abcdef";
string[] a = new string[s.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
    a[i] = s[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Actually, although both of your examples will give you the same string array in the end, the second ("older") way is considerably faster.  LINQ has to do a fair amount of overhead translation before breaking the code down to what is, essentially, the second set of code.  Try a timing test; the LINQ takes more than twice as long as the "longhand" example.

Comment: I suspect that there is something wrong with your method of timing.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

```
"abcdef".ToCharArray();
```

Comment: He said `string` array, not `char` array. Note that if you could `String.Split` on the empty `char` between each `char` in the `string` the result would be a `string[]`. This seems to be the behavior he is seeking.

Comment: My bad. I took liberties trying to interpret the improper grammar of his question, but my interpretation was clearly wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could use linq and do:

```
string value = "abcdef";
string[] letters = value.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

This would get you an array of strings instead of an array of chars.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just

```
string value="abcd";

value.ToCharArray();

textbox1.Text=Convert.toString(value[0]);
```

to show the first letter of the string; that would be 'a' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Bit more bulk than those above but i don't see any simple one liner for this.

```
List<string> results = new List<string>; 

foreach(Char c in "abcdef".ToCharArray())
{
   results.add(c.ToString());
}


results.ToArray();  <-- done
```

What's wrong with string.split???